# Null check operator used on a null value in dart code

Tags: dart

I am trying to check if a registry path exists, and if not then it creates it and sets the value to 0x0. If it does exist, then it looks at the value and returns a number based on what the value is.
Here is my code:

```
class SystemPrivilegesState {
  Future<int> getSystemPrivKey() async {
    String? state = '';
    try {
      final key1 = Registry.openPath(RegistryHive.localMachine,
          path: r'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PolicyManager\x\x\x');
      state = key1.getValueAsString("value");
    } catch (e){
      var shell = PRS.Shell();
      await shell.run('''
      reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\x\\x\\x\\x/v value /d 0x0 /f
        ''');
      return 2;
    }
    if (state != null) {
      if (state == "0x1") {
        var shell = PRS.Shell();
        await shell.run('''reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\x\\x\\x\\x/v value /d 0x0 /f''');

        return 0;
      }
      else if (state == "0x0") {

        return 1;
      }
      else {

        return 3;
      }
    }
    else {
      return 4;
    }
  }
}
```

Not sure why I am getting the null check operator.

Comment: what's the return type of `shell.run()` ?

Comment: @Delwinn It is a string, the shell.run() commands do work fine when I run them in the terminal.

Comment: which line are you getting the null error?